# How to call MVC ChildActionOnly Controller Action using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a DropDownListFor that is in a Partial View. On change it fires a jQuery script, but Fiddler shows an HTTP 500 Error:

```
The action 'LanguageListPartial' is accessible only by a child request.
```

The calling script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#SelectedLanguage').on('change', function () {
            var culture = $(this).val();
            $('#test').load("/Account/LanguageListPartial/" + culture, function () {
                location.reload(true);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I wouldn't want that Controller Action called directly so it is decorated with `[ChildActionOnly]`. I realize that it's being called directly with the jQuery `.load()`.

Is there a way to keep the `ChildActionOnly` restriction and still call it from jQuery with the `.on('change' ...)` event?

Comment: no way to do that having attribute assigned

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cant do that. The whole point of the `ChildActionOnly` attribute is to prevent it being invoked as a result of a user request.

Comment: I accept your answer disappointing as it is. I suppose there's no harm in someone hitting that URL. It'll just display a dropdown for them I believe. Is there any way of detecting in the Controller Action that it's being called from jQuery? I mean, I saw there was an `Request.IsAjaxRequest` boolean, but .load() isn't Ajax. Maybe I should rewrite the jQuery to use Ajax and check that boolean. That would solve it?

Comment: If you do use AJAX, then you can decorate your action methods with an AjaxOnly attribute as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23900411/mvc-set-accessibility-level-on-a-method-called-from-ajax/23900475#23900475)

Comment: The Partial View is also used from other View pages that won't call it using AJAX (or jQuery).

Answer (score 12):

First : Create a Custom Attribute that supports both ChildActionOnly and Ajax Functionality:

```
public class AjaxChildActionOnlyAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
        public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo)
        {
            return controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest() || controllerContext.IsChildAction;
        }
}
```

Then : Use above created attribute for your partial View:

```
[AjaxChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult LanguageListPartial(string id)
{
  //Function Logic
}
```