# Restrict MVC action to a contentType

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-type

Is where any attribute in MVC that restricts an action method so that the method handles only accept `contentType: 'application/json'` requests?

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetLastestPosts(int categoryID, int lastPostID)
{
    var list = Posts.GetPostsByRootCategoryIDForAjax(categoryID, lastPostID);

    return new JsonResult()
    {
        Data = list
    };
}
```

Comment: There is no built in attribute, but you could create your own, for example an [AjaxOnlyAttribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23900411/mvc-set-accessibility-level-on-a-method-called-from-ajax/23900475#23900475) to restrict calls to ajax requests

Comment: You're probably better off using Web API in this instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any out of box feature which can restrict requests based on ContentType.But you can always write custom Action Filter and make the necessary restrictions there.

```
public class RestrictionAttribute : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {

    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //Check for the content type take decision based on that.
    }
}
```