# mvc view with ajax not showing correct data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, asp.net-ajax

Good day,

I am refactoring my code from a legacy project. My view previously was rendering data from an api controller:

```
   ///just a portion of code, the important thing here is that I am using
//a foreach to add new data to the view.
 $.ajax({
            url: "/Api/ProfesorCurso/ConseguirCursosProfesor",
            type: "Get",
            success: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
                    $('<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12"><div class="thumbnail">' +
            '<a href="/ProfesorCurso/Editar/' + data[i].Id + '" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Editar</a><h3 class="centrar">' + data[i].Titulo + '</h3><a href="ProfesorModulo/index?CursoId=' + data[i].Id + '">' +
            '<img src="' + data[i].ImagenUrl + '"/></a><p>' + data[i].Descripcion + '</p></div>'
                    ).appendTo("#cursosdisponibles");
                    console.log(data[i]);
                }
```

The Api controller was doing this

```
    [HttpGet]

    public IHttpActionResult GetCursoProfesor(string ProfesorId = null)
    {
        ProfesorId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var result = _profesorCursoClass.GetCursoProfessor(ProfesorId);
        if (result == null) return BadRequest();
        return Ok(result); //IENumerable of myDto
    }
```

For clarification, this is the code executed to get the result

```
   public IEnumerable<HskDto> GetHskProfessor(string ProfesorId)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ProfesorId)) return null;
        var CursoProfesor = _dbContext.NivelHsk.Include(c => c.User).Where(c => c.UserId == ProfesorId);
        if (CursoProfesor == null) return null;
        var HskDto = CursoProfesor.ToList().Select(Mapper.Map<NivelHsk, HskDto>).ToList();
        if (!HskDto.Any()) return null;
        return HskDto;
    }
```

Now what I did to refactor is to avoid using api, and starting using an mvc controller

```
private ProfesorHsk _profesorHsk;
    public ProfesorCursoController()
    {
        _profesorHsk = new ProfesorHsk();
    }
//more code....
//...
   [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<HskDto> ConseguirCursosProfesor(string ProfesorId = null)
    {
        ProfesorId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var result = _profesorHsk.GetHskProfessor(ProfesorId);          
        return result;
    }
```

The only change I did to the view was just to modify the url from ajax

```
url: "/ProfesorCurso/ConseguirCursosProfesor",
```

With this url, my program is hiting the mvc controller, when I render data I get this
[image: my result]
and in my view this
[image]

This is an inspection from the view, I used console.log(data[i]); 
As you can see, it reads: system generic list (projectname) dto.hskdto

[image]

what is going on? how can I avoid this problem? I just want to show the database data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your mvc controller to return a `JsonResult`

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult ConseguirCursosProfesor(string ProfesorId = null)
{
    ProfesorId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var result = _profesorHsk.GetHskProfessor(ProfesorId);          
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The `Json()` method serializes your data to json. Note also you need the `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` argument because you are making a GET.

It is also recommended that you use `@Url.Action()` to generate the url

```
url: '@Url.Action("ConseguirCursosProfesor", "ProfesorCurso")',
```

Since you probably do not want users navigating to that method via the address bar, you can consider adding an `[AjaxOnly]` attribute as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23900411/mvc-set-accessibility-level-on-a-method-called-from-ajax/23900475#23900475).

In addition, you code for building the html is fragile, difficult to read and debug - and what you have shown is not valid since you missing a closing `</div>` tag. Consider using creating a 'template' that can be cloned, added to the DOM and updated. The template would be

```
<div id="template" style="display:none;">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm editar">Editar</a>
            <h3 class="centrar"></h3>
            <a class="index" href="">
                <img class="image" src="" /> //data[i].ImagenUrl
            </a>
            <p class="description">data[i].Descripcion</p>
        </div>
    </div> // you are missing this in your code
</div>
```

And the script would be

```
var parent = $('#cursosdisponibles');
var editarUrl = '@Url.Action("Editar", "ProfesorCurso");
var indexUrl = '@Url.Action("Index", "ProfesorCurso");
$.ajax({
    ....
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, item) {
            var html = $('#template').html();
            var clone = $(html).appendTo(parent);
            clone.find('.editar').attr('href', editarUrl + '/' + item.Id);
            clone.find('.centrar').text(item.Titulo);
            clone.find('.index').attr('href', indexUrl + '?CursoId' + item.Id);
            clone.find('.image').attr('src', item.ImagenUrl);
            clone.find('.description').text(item.Descripcion);
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: thank you very much! one more thing, now when I inspect the view with console, I am not getting any data displayed with the console.log(data[i])..why could it be happening?

Comment: That should work fine, but `i < data.length - 1` seems strange - it should be `i < data.length` (if there was only one item in the collection it would equate to `i < 0` so the loop would not be executed

Comment: That code you have for building the html in the loop is not good. When I get some time, I'll update the answer with some suggest improvements.

Comment: thank you very much, I appreciate a lot your time , I am using bootstrap 3.3.7 in the current project, I think that the legacy one uses 4+

Comment: one more thing please, why do I get the error >>find is not a function? are you using something in special?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169469/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-ev-vk).

Comment: thanks I found the solution  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49945218/find-is-not-a-function-jquery?noredirect=1#comment86907115_49945218